# Passé Composé with rentrer?

Tags: passé-composé

I just got my exam back and I am a little confused on why the following question was marked incorrect.
The question wanted me to translate:

> I did not return until last Thursday

Into French, so my answer was,

> Je ne suis pas rentré jeudi dernier

The only issue I can think of is the verb, but I thought to make the verb *rentrer* passé composé, you just removed the *-er* ending and replaced it with an *é*. Does anyone see what the issue might be?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT
 I completely forgot that the question stated that we had to use *jusqu' à* in our response. So my answer read: *Je ne suis pas rentré jusqu'à jeudi dernier*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote ***jusqu'à*** was required to be used in the translation.

The issue is using a negative statement before *jusqu'à* is not idiomatic French.

> *Je ne suis pas rentré jusqu'à jeudi dernier.* (odd, unused)

Using *avant* as user58319 suggested in a comment is a right way to tell it:

> *Je ne suis pas rentré avant jeudi dernier.*

However, it doesn't comply with the requirement. Replacing the first part by a positive phrase is is way to do it:

> *Je me suis absenté jusqu'à jeudi dernier*.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is not about the passé composé, but the translation of "until last Thursday".

"I did not return until last Thursday" means you returned last Thursday **and not before.** The translation would be as follows:

"Je ne suis rentré **que** jeudi dernier"

"Je ne suis pas rentré jeudi dernier, on the other hand, means "I did not return last Thursday". You could thus have returned on Wednesday or on Friday.

I hope the explanation was useful!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I completely forgot that the question stated that we had to use _jusqu' à_ in our response. So my answer read: _Je ne suis pas rentré jusqu'à jeudi dernier_, therefore would it still be caused by the translation of _until last Thursday_?

Comment: Chris, please edit and update your question with these new elements.

Comment: Je ne suis pas rentré AVANT jeudi dernier.